# PostgreSQL Like query for jsonb column data

Tags: postgresql, sql-like, jsonb

here column **details_js** is of type jsonb and I want to check if the json contains certain string.
What am i doing wrong with below query ?

```
select * 
from emp_details 
where details_js->'$.*' like '%somestring%'
```

Comment: i see it's working with following details_js::text ... but is this correct approach in case json is large ? OR any other efficient solutions if any would be appretiated.

Answer (score 1):

`details_js->'$.*'` won't work, it literally checks if there is a key with `'$.*'`

You need to unnest all elements in the JSON value to do this, e.g. with an EXISTS condition:

```
select d.*
from emp_details d
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_each_text(d.details_js) as x(ky,value)
              where value like '%somestring%');
```

If you are using Postgres 12 you could use a JSON path expression:

```
select *
from emp_details
where details_js @? '$.* ? (@ like_regex ".*somestring.*" flag "i")'
```

Comment: `jsonb_each_text` doesn't work on arbitrarily nested data. +1 for JSON paths though!

Comment: @Bergi: given the fact that the questions contains `->` I doubt there is "*arbitrarily nested data*" but yes, that wouldn't handle it. But neither would the JSON path expression.

Answer (score 0):

you should to use a operator [`->>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html). This operator ensure result in text format.

```
postgres=# select (jsonb '{"a":"AHOJ","b":"NAZDAR"}')->'b' like '%NAZ%';
ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb ~~ unknown
LINE 1: select (jsonb '{"a":"AHOJ","b":"NAZDAR"}')->'b' like '%NAZ%'...
                                                    ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
postgres=# select (jsonb '{"a":"AHOJ","b":"NAZDAR"}')->>'b' like '%NAZ%';
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│ t        │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```